# Does Allah love us?

Tags: practical-islam, allah

I know Allah is the most merciful towards us but does He love us? For example, Christians’ view of God is seeing him as “love” and “light”. For them, you can speak to him whenever and however you want and build a relationship with him. For us, it’s more just obligatory actions and only to worship Him. But does He also love us in the same sense, can we build a relationship with Him?

Answer (score 4):

> For them, you can speak to him whenever and however you want and build a relationship with him. For us, it’s more just obligatory actions and only to worship Him.

This is a false understanding you have of Islam.

Loving Allah and doing good deeds so that He loves us is an essential part of Islam. You should speak to God whenever and however you want, complain about your issues to Him, trust in Him, and seek his love.

The obligatory are simply the bare minimum a person needs to do. They are not the end of everything.

Allah loves people who do good and build a relationship with Him.

Allah says:

> And do good; indeed, Allah loves the doers of good. (2:195)

> Indeed, Allah loves those who are constantly repentant and loves those who purify themselves. (2:222)

> indeed, Allah loves those who fear Him. (3:76)

> And Allah loves the steadfast. (3:146)

> Indeed, Allah loves those who rely [upon Him]. (3:159)

Answer (score 2):

You can get closer to Allah by worshiping him.

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Allah says: ‘Whoever takes a close friend
> of Mine as an enemy, I declare war on him. My slave does not draw
> closer to Me by anything more beloved to Me than that which I have
> **made obligatory upon him**, and My slave continues to draw closer to Me
> by doing naafil (supererogatory) deeds **until I love him**,..."

[Al-Bukhaari (6502)](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/81/91)

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as this way:

Despite the immense biggest sin they (Christians) do which is Shirk (believing God has a son and Jesus died on the cross) he still provides them with:

- Food & water
- Safety
- A roof over their heads
- Children
- Happiness

And many other blessings.

What about atheists? Same thing.
What about gays? Same thing.
What about those who commit the worst of sins? Same thing.

We as Muslims can go a whole day without praying, reading Quran, and essentially not remembering Allah yet he still provides for us.

Allah’s mercy reaches everyone regardless.
But that doesn’t mean you’re safe from the punishment in the afterlife and day of judgement.

His mercy is even more than a mother’s mercy on her child. Just think, a mother would do so much for her child but Allah will provide mercy tenfold (maybe even more). It’s a curse we Muslims can’t understand the immense mercy the Lord has for us.

This world is a chance for people to reflect, to see the message and take heed of Allah.
We most certainly can build a relationship with him and that’s by constantly remembering Him and His mercy because regardless of the sins we cost ourselves in.

> “My mercy embraces all things” 
> **-Qur’an 7:156**

> “Verily My mercy overpowers My anger” 
>  **-Bukhari**

Answer (score 1):

*I know Allah is the most merciful towards us but does He love us?*

Love is a human feeling. In fact, the English word stands even for two related but different human feelings; other  languages such as Greek have two different words: έρωτας for the love between men and women, related to sexual attraction, and αγάπη for the caring love like parents to children, a feeling that we can have towards any living creature.

This caring for His living creatures is also immanent to God. As love is a human feeling; the Quran also uses the word يُحِبُّ ,sometimes translated «He likes» and sometimes «He loves», (passages see answer from TheZ) and the message that God cares for us is omnipresent.

*For them, you can speak to him whenever and however you want and build a relationship with him.*

Jesus (p.b.u.h) taught to pray to God addressing Him «Father». Similar to the word «love», this word has two meanigs: The biological father, and the protecting, caring father. Here, Arabic has two different words: (ab, آب) for the biological father and (wāli, وَلِي) for the protector. The Quran says that God is our Wāli [2:107].

We can and we should also pray to God our protector, our Wāli, whenever we want. Traditions may be different. God is the same.